# How to upload multiple images using CreateView in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a page, where user can create post. I want to give him a possibility to add multiple images to this post at the same page, but I don't know how to do it. There is my code:

models.py

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    ACTIVITY_CHOICES = [
        ('active', 'Active'),
        ('inactive', 'Inactive')
    ]
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='title')
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name='description')
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='tag')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='author')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    activity = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=ACTIVITY_CHOICES, default='inactive')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'post'
        verbose_name_plural = 'posts'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog_detail', args=[str(self.pk)])


class Image(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=user_directory_path)
```

forms.py

```
class BlogForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Blog
        fields = '__all__'


class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    file_field = forms.ImageField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': 'multiple'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ('image', )
```

views.py

```
class BlogCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Blog
    template_name = 'blog/create_blog.html'
    fields = ['title', 'description', 'tag']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.author = self.request.user
        self.object.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

create_post.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Create post</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Create post</h2>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" value="save">Create post</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I think models, forms and html are ok and all I need is to make some changes in views.py, but what exactly I don't know.

Comment: Nope ,your forms are not okay.i think it should be  `file_field=forms.ImageField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True})`

Answer (score 0):

You want a formset.

Checkout `ìnlineformset_factory` : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets

This will allow you to maintain multiple records for the `Image` model within the form for the Blog.

FE stuff is a little clunky, so you may need some extra JS if you want to make it work in a "prettier" way (or `htmx` maybe), but this will get you up and running.